# If i have a my cordinate , i want to get every cordinated in the radius of 5 km

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, filtering

i have the database of many events ,i want filter out the events happening within 5 kms of radius from my location.Currently i am doing it using haversine running every event in a for loop,which is very time consuming can anyone suggest an alternative for this method

The method i am currently using is haversine in a for loop for comparing every event and thats not a proper way

Edit:For claryfying i am using postgres db and  using django filter.

```py
class Event(models.Model):
    latitude =models.CharField(max_length = 
                   800,null=True,blank=True)
    longitude =models.CharField(max_length = 
                   800,null=True,blank=True)
```

this is the structure of my model

Comment: Which database are you using? Django provides GeoDjango for storing and querying spatial data https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/gis/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.